# Inter-Process Communications between Python and C++ using local file sockets?

Tags: python, c++, sockets, ipc

I have a c++ program which creates a local socket bound to "/tmp/.mysocket" and waits to receive data from that socket.  The way it is set up, raw binary data would be sent to the socket and loaded into the following C++ structure:

```
struct StateVariable
{
    char Name[64];
    int E[8];
};
```

The C++ program listens for input using recvfrom:

```
int nBytes = recvfrom(SD,&DataReceived,sizeof(StateVariable)/sizeof(char),0,(sockaddr*)&SentFrom,&size);
```

The server is just using the standard AF_UNIX and SOCK_DGRAM to create the socket.

My questions is relating to python: How do I send data to the local socket bound to /tmp/.mysocket using python?  I am not using AF_INET or opening a specific port for this.

I can use python's socket library to describe the socket, but I can't find any resource that discusses binding a socket to a file in python and sending data to that socket.  The documentation for the socket library only discusses using AF_INET and SOCK_DGRAM for local sockets bound to a port number at 127.0.0.1, but I'm not doing that.

How do I get python to send data to a socket bound to a file?  Is there an example python program that does just that (maybe a client/server pair that demonstrates this functionality)?  As long as I can get python to send data to a local file socket, I can figure out the rest.

Comment: Remote procedure call mechanism was programmed 10000 times. Google for already existing method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Python `socket` library is a fairly thin wrapper around the socket interface you're familiar with from C++.  See [socket documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html).

It's going to look something like this:

```
import socket
import struct 

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.connect('/tmp/...')
s.send(struct.pack('64s8i', ...))
```

Answer (score 0):

You just change `AF_INET` to `AF_UNIX` and then `.connect(address)` and/or `.bind(address)` methods accept path to a file (instead of `(host, port)` pair). Other then that everything else works pretty much the same.